# Folder name as calculated field

Tags: content-type, calculated-column, folder, calculated-column-formula

I've created a Library which consists of two Folder Content-types.

1. Customer
2. Prequalfication

I'm looking to create a calculated column in the Prequalfication folder content-type which fetches the 'name' column of the of the Customer folder.

Is this possible?

Comment: Come again? Fetches the 'name' column from which item in the Customer folder? Are you sure that this data architecture makes sense? Can you explain the bigger picture of what you want to achieve? Why two folder ***content types***?

Comment: No, I'm not sure this data architecture makes is the correct to use.

Comment: How do you expect anybody to be able to help you with the information you have provided?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to post to comment above. No, I'm not sure this data architecture is the correct to use. I'm new to SharePoint and is learning by doing at the moment. What I'm trying to achieve is to have metadata and documents stored in a folder view. On top, there's the Customer [top-folder] which has a specific set of metadata. Below the customer, there are Prequalfications [sub-folder] which has another set of metadata and in the prequalfication folder the documents are stored. I've tried to draw it: http://i.imgur.com/Hajn7I3.png I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at Document Sets. A document set is a type of folder. A document set can have specific metadata columns. Inside a document set you can create or upload documents. The documents can inherit some or all metadata from the parent document set.

A three layer hierarchy with different sets of metadata at each tier cannot be done with SharePoint out of the Box.

SharePoint MVP Michal Pisarek has a good [introduction to SharePoint 2010 Document sets](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2012/06/documents-sets-vs-folders-in-sharepoint-2010/)

There is also this [Introduction to Document Sets](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-document-sets-HA101782466.aspx) from Microsoft and many more resources can be found with a quick web search.

Comment: Thanks teylyn. I'll have a look at Document Sets and see if it's something I can use.

Comment: I've been reading about Document Sets and I like the idea. However, as you mentioned, I don't think it's possible to make a three layer hierarchy - or a document set within a document set.

Comment: You may want to move away from the "folder" thinking mentality. Why do you need that hierarchy? Maybe it can be created with metadata. Managed metadata has hierarchies. What business reason is there to have three tiers of a hierarchy with different sets of columns for each tier? A data architect might be able to simplify that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, teyltn. I ended up using Document Sets with grouping the documents. That worked perfect for me. The folder thinking mentality is just a remnant from using Windows :)